# Как убрать дубли главной страницы

Tags: .htaccess

Заметил в выдаче несколько страниц главной - `site.ru/?=&page7`, `site.ru/?page&page9` и т.п.

При этом у меня вообще нет функционала с get-параметрами для главной страницы

Как мне сделать общий редирект, чтобы если скажем после слеша `?` знак - всегда редиректит на главную, но чтобы это работало только для главной страницы, чтобы со страницы `site.ru/page/?ddd=asd` не редиректило.

Comment: Нашли решение вашей проблемы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^site.ru/?(.*)$  site.ru [L,R=301]
```

--- Добавлено ---

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^site.ru/?(.*)$  site.ru/index.php [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Это не работает

Comment: Поменял код в ответе

Comment: И это не работает)) Оба варианта пробовал

Comment: Тогда так, есть ли предыдущие правила замены? Ведь просто так знак ? после УРЛ не ставят...

Comment: И так не работает) В htaccess кроме этого ничего даже больше не добавляю. Решил забить и просто прописать rel canonical

Comment: Еще добавка в ответе...